# SMS Character Limit with AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, sms

We're using AMPScript to create a send log for all email and SMS sends. In MobileConnect, I can include the AMPScript and the SMS text fine and it's reported as one send however, when using Journey Builder to create SMS content and adding the AMPScript, it reads it as SMS message text and so is being sent as 5 or 6 messages instead of one. My example SMS was recorded as three sends in the Send Log. Is this normal for Journey Builder and SMS functionality?

Comment: Are you including the ampscript directly in your message? Or are you storing it in a code snippet content block, and referencing it using e.g. contentblockbykey ampscript function?

Comment: Hi @LukasLunow Yes in this instance the AMPScript is being added directly to the SMS content. Can code snippets and reference blocks be used in SMS?

Comment: You can use the ContentBlockbykey function in a SMS message but need to be sure that you call only Code Snippets with AMPscript and/or text in them. The other content block types utilize HTML which will not render in a SMS message. This should reduce the overall number of characters in your message.

Comment: Thanks @LukasLunow this seems to have resolved the issue. It's taken the character count down from over 500 (all AMPScript) to 31 and is then tracked in the send log as one send instead of 4

Comment: Great! So I thought. I have added this as an answer to your question. Please click on the checkmark on the left side, to mark the answer as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place your Ampscript in a code snippet content block, and reference it in your SMS message using `%%=ContentBlockByKey()=%%` function. This will greatly reduce the character count, as the Ampscript placed in the content block will not count towards your limit.

You need to be sure that you call only Code Snippets with AMPscript and/or text in them. The other content block types utilize HTML which will not render in a SMS message.

This should resolve your issue and allow you to log it as a single message and not as multiple.